# Kendo Tree View(for ASP.NET MVC) generates different html layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

There is a kendo popup window with a kendo TreeView on it, javascript is opening the popup like this:

```
var dialog = e.sender;
dialog.refresh({
    url: baseUrl,
    data: parameters,
    type: "POST"
}).center();
```

On backend, a controller reads data and returns an ActionResult object
`return this.View("MyView", editor);`

The popup is opened from 2 different places, from the first place TreeView DOM is generated
and displayed correctly, each group node has a `<div class="k-top">` with 3 span html elements placed side by side(first span displays expand/collapse node icon, second displays checkbox, third - tree node text):

[image]

In the second place, backend returns the same view with the same data but DOM is different and kendo TreeView is wrongly displayed. All 3 `span` elements are placed inside the checkbox span, and additional(4rd one) empty span is added `<span class="k-in"></span>`

[image]

Why does the second popup display kendo TreeView incorrectly?

Comment: Are both places referencing the exact same set of kendoui files? Same theme, css, js, same version?